# How to submit a form with pressing tab or enter (form contains hidden fields) in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, forms

form with pressing tab or enter (form contains hidden fields) in Angular Js.

Here is my controller code

```
    $scope.preview = function(pre)
    {
            $scope.master = angular.copy(pre);
    };
```

Here is my view template code

```
    <form ng-submit="preview(pre)" name="form" novalidate>


    <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.name" name='pre.name' value='{{item.name}}'ng-show="item.name==product.name">

    <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.sku" name='pre.sku' value='{{item.sku}}'ng-show="item.name==product.name">

    <input type="hidden" ng-model="item.price" name='pre.price' value='{{item.price}}'ng-show="item.name==product.name">

    <input ng-model="item.quantity" name='pre.quantity' value='{{item.quantity}}'ng-show="item.name==product.name"> // After changing the quantity then by pressing tab or enter the data have to submit

    </form>

    <pre>form = {{pre | json}}</pre> // have to show all the values which we giving in the form
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I can submit it.

Comment: BTW you should have this: `<pre>form = {{item | json}}</pre>` because `pre` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Having it submit on enter is easy: Add a submit button which isn't visible for the user: http://plnkr.co/edit/WFtx5tJydqCI2usK6FhP?p=preview
To have it submit on tab, you'll need to write a custom directive which listens to key events.
Also:

- When using ng-model, there's no need to set the value of an input
- `ng-show` on hidden inputs is not doing anything. If you want to omit these fields, use `ng-if`